# Exclude certain gems from rubygems "gem update" command

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a gem that I maintain purely for personal use that happens to have a name conflict with an old gem hosted on rubygems.org.  When I run `gem update`, the rubygems.org version is downloaded.  I would like to keep this from happening.  I know that I can specify explicitly what gems to include with `gem update`, but can I specify what to exclude?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure you can't, but you can script a solution fairly easily (on unix) with

```
gem list --local | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v YOUR_GEMNAME | xargs gem update
```

Also, I've been really impressed with the Rubygems source code the last several times I've looked at it, it probably wouldn't be very difficult to add this feature. They might accept a pull request for it.

Comment: thanks, I'll try this out... am maybe get around to submitting a pull request

Comment: You can also use **gem outdated** option and then update particularly gem one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Following on Joshua's answer, to selectively exclude gems from updating during `bundle update`, you can also do the following:

```
bundle list --name-only | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v YOUR_GEMNAME | grep -v YOUR_OTHER_GEMNAME | xargs -t bundle update
```

with the additional pipe `grep -v YOUR_OTHER_GEMNAME` showing how you can exclude multiple gems from the bundle update if desired.